# How can I use new HTTPS localhost certificate

Tags: ssl, asp.net-core, https, ssl-certificate, dotnet-dev-certs

I have a problem with HTTPS when I am running (`dotnet run`) my .NetCore application locally on Windows.
It was working till my localhost certificate expired…

[image]

I clean up old certificates and generated the new one by

```
dotnet dev-certs https –clean
dotnet dev-certs https –trust
```

I’ve verified that everything was added to certmgr (Personal and Trusted certs), but I have the same problem.
It is keep trying to use old certificate which expired.
I do not know why it is trying to use old “localhost” certificate after clean up certs…

Do you have any idea what should I do?.

Thank you,
Błażej

Comment: Refer to https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/13928 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.0&branch=pr-en-us-14568&tabs=visual-studio#troubleshoot-certificate-problems , check  platform specific suggestions in above links

Comment: And try manually  remove all the found certificates from both Personal and Trusted root certification authorities , try reinstall again .

Comment: @NanYu I am using Windows and I was trying every platform specific suggestions which are in above links

Comment: Do you try to manually remove certs from Personal and Trusted root certification authorities ,  and try reinstall again ?

Comment: Yes. I removed localhost certs from .Net Dev Cert and reinstalled them. It does not help me. Currently I am not using a HTTPS on localhost, so I can develop my things, but it will be nice to fix the problem for future

Comment: See full video here https://youtu.be/D5IqDcHyXSQ

Answer (score 36):

If not helps recreate cert by commands:

```
dotnet dev-certs https ––clean
dotnet dev-certs https ––trust
```

Clean all private keys from folder:

```
C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https
```

Comment: I've battled this issue for 2 days - cleaning the private keys did the trick. Thanks!!!

Comment: I will name my next child after @Maxim

Comment: Cleaning the private keys also did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: Same for me, this should be the aceppted answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to use two hyphens. The flag is `-t` or `--trust`, not `–trust` so the following should work:

```sh
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

You can also run the help command to see more info

```sh
dotnet dev-certs https --help
```

[image: dev-certs https help output]

**See Also**: [How to run `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55485511/1366033)