# AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot, NotValidTime

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, ssl-certificate

I am consistenly receiving the following error when developing and authenticating locally in Visual Studio:

> AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: NotValidTime, UntrustedRoot

Among others, it happens when using `HttpClient` to call one of our backend-endpoints (`localhost`) from one of our projects, so it all happens locally.

The certificate was signed/valid from this date last year, and has now run out after a year. None of the other developers on my team are receiving it or had the same problem.

I have then tried a lot of stuff, among others:

- `dotnet dev-certs https --clean`, `dotnet dev-certs https` and `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`, which sucessfully updated/re-created a certificate that expires in 2023 - still doesn't work/still receiving the same error though.
- Updating certificate in Microsoft Management Console as per these links

  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5427149/16805816
  - [IdentityServer: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032215/identityserver-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-pr)

We don't have a centralized authentication procedure - it is spread around the system in various places and scenarios, so I am not able to use workarounds like `if #DEBUG... //then ignore certificates`. I need to generate a valid certificate correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cleaning all private keys from the following folder did the trick (I only had one, that I just renamed, which did the trick):

`C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https`

Credit to [this SO-post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67182991/16805816) for the solution.

Comment: jade serpent guide you

Comment: I have experienced the same error but I don't have the ASP.NET folder in AppData\Roaming. Where else can I look?

Comment: @RealSollyM AppData folder is hidden by default (I believe). You need to change folder settings, so that you also see hidden folders

Comment: @mnc - There is no ASP.NET folder at all in my AppData\Roaming folder. I have enabled hidden items but it is still not there. And when I try to type the folder directly, I get the "Windows can't find ... Check the spelling and try again" error message.

Comment: @RealSollyM If you don't have the ASP.NET/Https folder, then I assume you don't have generated any certificates (because the folder only contains trusted certificates, as far as I know). Maybe you need to generate or trust https certificates. You can, among others, see how to do that in the 'SO-post answer' that I linked to above - I think its something like `dotnet dev-certs https ––clean`, `dotnet dev-certs https ––trust` etc

Answer (score 6):

In my case, my domain's SSL certificate has expired. So, please check your domain certificate expiry date.
The solution is to renew the domain certificate.

`Temporary solution:` Skip SSL certificate validation.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = 
    (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
{
    return true;
};

var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46626858/672891

Answer (score 4):

Delete your offending localhost certificates:

Control Panel -> Internet Options - > Content tab.

1. Click Certificates and remove the ones you no longer require.
2. Click the Clear SSL State button.

Follow instructions here to recreate new certificate for each of your localhost sites, paying attention to the port number:

https://improveandrepeat.com/2020/05/recreate-the-self-signed-https-certificate-for-localhost-in-iis-express

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. The problem has been solved in the meanwhile, and I have posted the solution I used in another answer, in case you are interested. I didn't get to try your solution in time, so that may also have worked.

Comment: I had the same issue this morning and my solution worked for me. Yours looks easier though!

Answer (score 0):

First enter these two commands

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

Then delete all the files in this path:

```
C:\Users\{User Name}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\leveldb
```