# ASP.NET Core 6 : httpclient error calling API when open Visual Studio with different User. AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient

I am creating an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app.

I have two applications, a client application (ClientUI) that calls an API.

Both applications are running in Visual Studio 2022.

The API is connected to a SQL database, and in order to have access to the database, I have to open Visual Studio as different user and use a user and password generated by BeyondTrust.

Using those credentials I have access to the database.

When I do an `HttpClient` call from the ClientUI to the API endpoint, I got this error

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.)'
>
> AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot

If a open Visual Studio with my credentials, I have no problem to connect to the endpoint (but is does not connect to the database).

My credentials are up to date. Those credentials are not available when I open Visual Studio with different user?

I read what it is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73403893/authenticationexception-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-because-of-errors-in), but I do not have a directory ASP.NET in this path `C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https`

Answer (score 0):

The Only solution I found was open both visual studio with the same user/password.