# Authorization on Win10 dev Blazor web to Blazor web API to SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio, rest, iis

I have my Windows 10 laptop with IIS10, SQL Server local install (standard out of the box Windows authentication settings), and Visual Studio 2022.

I have an API app (ASP.NET Core Web API project) that connects to my local SQL with connection string:

```
Server=localhost;Database=Shipwrecks;User id=apilogin;Password=xxxxx;TrustServerCertificate=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

I can publish and successfully run an API using https://localhost:8081/api/Expeditions/1001.

in Visual Studio I have a Blazor web project that calls the API above.  When I run the project in debug mode it retrieves from the API perfectly.  When I publish the website to local IIS and run the page I get the error at the bottom.

Any idea why the API is acting differently when called from a web page as opposed to entered in the browser?

Thanks for any suggestions!

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
at BlazorAuthTest.Components.Pages.ExpeditionList.OnInitializedAsync() in C:\dev\Shipwrecks Project\WebAuthTest\BlazorAuthTest\BlazorAuthTest\Components\Pages\ExpeditionList.razor:line 56
```

I tried different parameters for the the connection string and the URL for the API I tried IP address, localhost, and machine name.

Comment: The error tells me there's a SQL authentication error.  What I don't understand is why I get the error from a published page but it works from a debug page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73403893/authenticationexception-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-because-of-errors-in

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that your application encountered a certificate validation issue while trying to make a secure connection to the API.

- You need to ensure that the SSL certificate used by your API is valid
  and that its root certificate is trusted. You can access the API in
  your browser and check the validity of the SSL certificate.
- If the certificate is self-signed, you need to ensure that your
  client trusts the certificate. In a production environment, you
  typically need to use a certificate signed by a trusted Certificate
  Authority (CA).
- Make sure that the SSL certificate used by your API project has a
  valid certificate chain.

Comment: When I look at my certificate (localhost API and web) from my browser they are both using a certificate issued by AO Kaspersky Lab (Kaspersky Anti-Virus Personal Root Certificate).  CN=localhost, O and OU = <Not Part Of Certificate>

The issue date is Aug 2023 and expired Aug 2024.

Not sure where else to check API cert

Comment: I tried removing and adding certificates multiple times, deleted and recreated the website, but the best I can do I get back to my original issue with the certificate chain.  I'm lost here!

Comment: If I rebuild my API app with app.UseHttpsRedirection and app.UseAuthorization commented out it works from the website with and http call.  I guess this is good enough for local development.  Hopefully when I move this to a production environment the certificate issue won't be there.  