# mac verify failure - Certification Exception while docker-compose up prevents ASPNETCORE Docker-Container start

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, microservices, ubuntu-18.04

first of all, i am not an expert in linux and certificate related topics. I try to code a webapi-service and publish it as a docker-container.

My Coding environment is a Visual Studio, running on Windows 10 in a VM. Here, everything is up and running.

My target environment is a Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with  Docker version 19.03.6-rc1.

Since i want to have multiple services in future, i try to use 'docker-compose up' which is not working as aspected.

---

Steps i do:

1. Code in Windows VS 2017
2. Publish on Docker.hub
3. Try to compose on Ubuntu

---

More detailed...

**1. Code in Windows VS 2017**

In Debug Mode, everything is working for me.

I have a docker-compose project and the api project. The docker-compose project includes the docker-compose.yml and an override file.

Here is my project in VS: [The Project in VS2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D92gU.png)

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

    services:
      logs.api:
        env_file: .env
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}logsapi
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: logs.api/Dockerfile
```

**docker-compose.override.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  logs.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44374
      - ConnectionString=${CONNECTION_STRING}
    ports:
      - "50530:80"
      - "44374:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY logs.api/logs.api.csproj logs.api/
RUN dotnet restore logs.api/logs.api.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/logs.api
RUN dotnet build logs.api.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish logs.api.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "logs.api.dll"]
```

---

**3. Try to compose on Ubuntu**

I try to compose in ubuntu with the following command and modified .yml files. Before i login to docker hub with `docker login`.

Compose command: `sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.production.yml up`

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  logs.api:
    env_file: .env
    image: autoempire/logsapi
```

**docker-compose.production.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  logs.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44374
      - ConnectionString=${CONNECTION_STRING}
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=""
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/logs.api.pfx
    volumes:
      - ${HOME}/.aspnet/https:/https/
    ports:
      - "50530:80"
      - "44374:443"
    build:
      context: "http://${GIT_USR}:${GIT_PWD}@github.com/r...s/mymicroservices.git#master"
      dockerfile: logs.api/Dockerfile
```

Here you see, i already changed the volumes. With the secrets i am not sure what to do, so i removed them, since i do not have any password for the cert. But this is maybe another topic.

I added the  `ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password` and `ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path` regarding to some usefull descriptions on stackoverflow and created a [self signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55485511/how-to-run-dotnet-dev-certs-https-trust) on ubuntu which i moved to `~/.aspnet/https/logs.api.pfx`.

This is what i get:

```
logs.api_1  | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
logs.api_1  |       User profile is available. Using '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
logs.api_1  | crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
logs.api_1  |       Unable to start Kestrel.
logs.api_1  | Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:23076071:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_parse:mac verify failure
logs.api_1  |    at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslPkcs12Reader.Decrypt(SafePasswordHandle password)
logs.api_1  |    at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.PkcsFormatReader.TryReadPkcs12(OpenSslPkcs12Reader pfx, SafePasswordHandle password, Boolean single, ICertificatePal& readPal, List`1& readCerts)
logs.api_1  |    at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.PkcsFormatReader.TryReadPkcs12(SafeBioHandle bio, SafePasswordHandle password, Boolean single, ICertificatePal& readPal, List`1& readCerts, Exception& openSslException)
logs.api_1  |    at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromBio(SafeBioHandle bio, SafePasswordHandle password)
logs.api_1  |    at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromFile(String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
logs.api_1  |    at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
logs.api_1  |    at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)
logs.api_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.LoadCertificate(CertificateConfig certInfo, String endpointName)
logs.api_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.LoadDefaultCert(ConfigurationReader configReader)
logs.api_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Load()
logs.api_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.ValidateOptions()
logs.api_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
logs.api_1  |
logs.api_1  | Unhandled Exception: Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:23076071:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_parse:mac verify failure
logs.api_1  |    at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslPkcs12Reader.Decrypt(SafePasswordHandle password)
logs.api_1  |    at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.PkcsFormatReader.TryReadPkcs12(OpenSslPkcs12Reader pfx, SafePasswordHandle password, Boolean single, ICertificatePal& readPal, List`1& readCerts)
logs.api_1  |    at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.PkcsFormatReader.TryReadPkcs12(SafeBioHandle bio, SafePasswordHandle password, Boolean single, ICertificatePal& readPal, List`1& readCerts, Exception& openSslException)
logs.api_1  |    at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromBio(SafeBioHandle bio, SafePasswordHandle password)
logs.api_1  |    at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromFile(String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
logs.api_1  |    at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
logs.api_1  |    at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)
logs.api_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.LoadCertificate(CertificateConfig certInfo, String endpointName)
logs.api_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.LoadDefaultCert(ConfigurationReader configReader)
logs.api_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Load()
logs.api_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.ValidateOptions()
logs.api_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
logs.api_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
logs.api_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
logs.api_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
logs.api_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
logs.api_1  |    at logs.api.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/logs.api/Program.cs:line 18
reco_logs.api_1 exited with code 139
```

The location of the certificate in the production.yml seems to be ok because when I change it, I get an error like "file not found". I tried a certificate with and without a password. It does not matter... maybe not really good registered?

Comment: - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="" has to be without ""like ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=mypassword. And it works :/