# Install ssl certificate for ASP.NET Core hosted on nginx on raspberrypi (raspbian)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl, nginx, .net-core

I need to install an **https certificate** for my **asp.net core** application hosted on **nginx** on my **raspberrypi3**.

I tried `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` but on linux I cannot run this command.

How can i install an ssl certificate for my application?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55485511/how-to-run-dotnet-dev-certs-https-trust)

Comment: @MartinFrøhlich 
I think so, Excuse me and thank you.