# Ubuntu 20.04 Chrome not trusting self signed certificate in hosted Blazor WASM project

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, .net-core, https, blazor-webassembly

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and working on .NET core 3.1. I just started a project for a "hosted blazor WASM" application (.net server hosting blazor WASM).

It is my understanding that in order to get client side debugging in VS code, I need to make sure that I have a dev cert in place (self signed certificate for localhost).

After 3 days of trying, I can't get chrome to trust my project when it hits the https://localhost:5001/ url. It's always not trusted.

Here is what I've done so far:

- I've tried running `dotnet dev-certs https -v` and converting the
  cert with openssl. Which doesn't work.
- I've also tried the suggested answer in this post [how-to-run-dotnet-dev-certs-https-trust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55485511/how-to-run-dotnet-dev-certs-https-trust)
- I've also tried to use mkcert which is supposed to automate all this for you. It tells me that the certificate was added to the chrome trust store (but when I launch my project, chromes opens and it is still not trusted).

I honestly I'm at a lost, because anything I try, just doesn't work. I don't know what else to try.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Having the very same issue when started development in Linux, I gathered the two most useful approaches that worked for me into a [github](https://github.com/steliosgiakoumidis/Dotnet-TrustCertificate-Ubuntu) repository