# ASP.Net Core 3 The remote certificate is invalid on MacOs

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt, identityserver4

When I try to call an API method using identityserver4, I tried before on Windows and it is working fine only in Mac OS I faced this issue and I don´t know what is happened and how to resolve it.
I can access to https://localhost:6001/.well-known/openid-configuration and I can login correctly, also I tried to run this command: dotnet dev-certs https --trust and run correctly but that is not fixing the issue.
This is the error in the terminal:

`` fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3] Exception occurred while processing message. System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'System.String'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ThrowIfExceptional() at System.Net.Security.SslStream.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__65_1(IAsyncResult iar) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'System.String'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ThrowIfExceptional() at System.Net.Security.SslStream.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__65_1(IAsyncResult iar) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3] Exception occurred while processing message. System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'. at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'. at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3] Exception occurred while processing message. System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'. at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'. at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3] Exception occurred while processing message. System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'. at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'. at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) ``

my Startup.cs is :

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "https://localhost:6001";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.Audience = "myApiName";
                });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dotnet dev-certs don't work on Linux or Mac.](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7246) 
That is because the dev-tools issue an incorrect root certificate.
Windows apparently accepts incorrect root certificates...

What you need to do is this:

- [create a root certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59702094/155077)
- add this to your machine's root certificate store
- sign the SSL-certificate with that root
  certificate.

Alternatively, you can just ignore SSL-errors:

```
if (hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
{
   System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
      (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
}
```

Or you can write a more complex Validation-Callback, that just ignores untrusted root certificates:

```
/// <summary>
///     This is to take care of SSL certification validation which are not issued by Trusted Root CA.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
/// <param name="certificate">The certificate.</param>
/// <param name="chain">The chain.</param>
/// <param name="sslPolicyErrors">The errors.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
/// <code></code>
public static bool RemoteCertValidate(object sender
    , System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate
    , System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain
    , System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    // If the certificate is a valid, signed certificate, return true.
    if (sslPolicyErrors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Logger.Current.Error("X509Certificate [{0}] Policy Error: '{1}'", certificate.Subject, sslPolicyErrors);


    // If there are errors in the certificate chain, look at each error to determine the cause.
    if ((sslPolicyErrors & System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) != 0)
    {
        if (chain != null && chain.ChainStatus != null)
        {
            foreach (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatus status in chain.ChainStatus)
            {
                if ((certificate.Subject == certificate.Issuer) &&
                   (status.Status == System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot))
                {
                    // Self-signed certificates with an untrusted root are valid. 
                    continue;
                }
                else if (status.Status == System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.NotTimeValid)
                {
                    // Ignore Expired certificates
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (status.Status != System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError)
                    {
                        // If there are any other errors in the certificate chain, the certificate is invalid,
                        // so the method returns false.
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            } // Next status 

        } // End if (chain != null && chain.ChainStatus != null) 

        // When processing reaches this line, the only errors in the certificate chain are 
        // untrusted root errors for self-signed certificates (, or expired certificates). 
        // These certificates are valid for default Exchange server installations, so return true.
        return true;
    } // End if ((sslPolicyErrors & System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) != 0) 

    return false;
}
```

And add that to ServerCertificateValidationCallback:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
    new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(RemoteCertValidate);
```

Comment: Thanks , very helpful!

Comment: The linked issue explains that it's not due to invalid certificates or Windows accepting invalid certificates - it doesn't, which is why self-signed certificates have to be trusted explicitly even on Windows. Its' due to [an OpenSSL bug](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/1418) that was fixed this July

Comment: Actually, you need to have "Certificate Signing" as an additional attribute on the KeyUsage field - this is not really an OpenSSL bug, it's OpenSSL strictly adhering to standards. If this has been changed, it was not a bug, but an unnecessary added feature. A root certificate is for "Certificate Signing", so it should have this attribute. If the root-certificate doesn't have this attribute, then the certificates signed by this root certificate should not be classified as "valid" - apparently it can be - but IMHO it shouldn't. Yes this is a bug in .NET certificate generation.

Comment: But why fix .NET when you can "fix" OpenSSL. Probably if they fixed .NET, they would have run into problems on Windows, that seems to be the real issue. But why fix Windows when you can fix OpenSSL. In order for something to be a "fix", it would have to be a bug in the first place. The typical Microsoft approach. Their software does not contain bugs, just undocumented "features". Speechless. I have nothing more to say than this.

Comment: Oh, and while I am on the subject of OpenSSL: In 2012, Azure was downed by a leap-year bug in the Windows SSL-implementation. 4 Years later, the same problem reoccured... Meaning it was still not fixed. Is that fixed by now ? Notice the continue for expired certificates ? For reference: https://www.wired.com/2012/03/azure-leap-year-bug/

Comment: the OpenSSL bug is fixed. i followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@brunoosiek/updating-openssl-latest-and-greatest-version-in-ubuntu-18-04-8f10ba4e2377) to install the latest version of openssl

Answer (score 0):

Your Mac does not trust the local development Windows certificate for localhost, you need to buy a get a real certificate that your Mac will trust. Perhaps use [LetsEncrypt](http://www.letsencrypt.com/) if you want a real trusted certificate for free.