# dotnet 5 CLI doesn't give https on centos 8

Tags: c#, .net-core, centos

I cannot get https to start on a centos 8 box using a 'framework dependant' published site.
Both have the same version of the `dotnet runtime 5.0.100`

When I run the command `dotnet run project.dll` on **windows** I get :

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
       Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
```

When I run the same project on **Centos 8** I only get

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: I am not, or nothing I can tell. dotnet command still runs successfully.

Comment: In windows you are using HTTP for port 5000 and HTTPS for port 5001.  So it looks like in Centos 8 you are failing the https (secure).  HTTPS does an authentication using TLS which requires a certificate and supports TLS 1.2/1.3 (1.0/1.1 no long works).  So I would read following : https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-mod-ssl-on-redhat-8

Comment: @jdweng I appreciate your comments and I will give it a read, although when downgrading to .net 3.1 I am able to get it hosting on 5000 and (https) 5001 on centos 8

Comment: Windows is working so you must use same in Centos 8.  If you use a sniffer you should see the TLS version which is usually 1.2 with windows then get centos working in same mode..  I is possible that you are running in 1.3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.Net Core application service only listening to Port 5000 on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52227372/asp-net-core-application-service-only-listening-to-port-5000-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Yes partly @IanKemp if you see my answer it says this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that .net 3.1/5 will look for a local development certificate here:
`/home/{user name} /.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/my`

It will not load https if this certificate is not present, you can set this up yourself from the appsettings file:

Once you have enabled these settings the application will start on the https settings. E.g.

```
"Kestrel": {
"Endpoints": {
  "HTTPS": {
    "Url": "https://localhost:5001",
    "Certificate": {
      "Path": "/etc/ssl/certs/<certificate.pfx>",
      "Password": "xyz123"
    }
  }
}}
```

Answer to this question can be found here :
[ASP.Net Core application service only listening to Port 5000 on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52227372/asp-net-core-application-service-only-listening-to-port-5000-on-ubuntu/52413068#52413068)

Microsoft documentation :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-5.0#endpoint-configuration